# Selecting one item in a listbox at a time

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have three list boxes in one Userform. I want a code that can perform this: Assuming I have previously selected an item in listbox1 and now I'm selecting another item in listbox2, the macro should automatically deselect the previously selected item in listbox1 and also in listbox3. 
I'm new to excel macros

I've tried the following but it isn't working

```
 Dim indexi as long
 indexi=Me.listbox1.listindex+1
 If Listbox1.selected(indexi) Then
    Listbox2.selected(indexi)=false
    Listbox3.selected(indexi)=false
 End if
```

Comment: you can try `Me.Listbox1.ListIndex = -1` to deselect in `Listbox2_Change()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalizing as answer, you can deselect the selected index using

```
Me.Listbox1.ListIndex = -1
```

and use in `Listbox2_Change()` function